# Разбиение кода на несколько функций

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется небольшой код:

```
price = float(input('Введите цену продажи:'))
def profits(a, b, c, d, f):
    i1 = round(b*c,1) # стоимость акций при продаже
    i2 = a*c # стоимость акций при покупки
    i3 = i2*f # комиссия биржи/депозитария при покупке
    i4 = i1*f # комиссия биржи/депозитария при продаже
    i6 = (i1-i2)*0.13 # 13% налог с разницы
    i7 = round(sum([i4,i6,i3])) # сумма затрат
    i8 = round((b*c-a*c)-i7) # чистая прибыль
    
    print(f'стоимость акции при покупке - {i2}\nстоимость акции при продаже - {i1}\nчистая прибыль - {i8}\nналоги/комиссии - {i7}')

profits(1807.3, price, 6, 0.13, 0.000725)
```

Хочу разбить его на несколько функций:

```
pricesale = float(input('Введите цену продажи:'))
def price (a,b,c):
    p1 = round(b*c,1)
    p2 = a*c
    return p1,p2

price(1807.3, pricesale, 6)

def commission (a,b):
    c1 = p1*b
    c2 = p2*b
    c3 = (p1-p2)*0.13
    return c1, c2, c3
    
commission(0.13, 0.000725)
    
def profits():
    p7 = round(sum([c1,c2,c3])) # сумма затрат
    p8 = round((p1-p2)-p7) # чистая прибыль
    return p7,p8
    
    print(f'стоимость акции при покупке - {p2}\nстоимость акции при продаже - {p1}\nчистая прибыль - {p8}\nналоги/комиссии - {p7}')
```

Подскажите правильно ли я передаю результаты вычисления из одной функции в другую ?
И как избавиться от ошибки которая возникает при запуске второго варианта:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/WF/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/итог продажи акций2.py", line 16, in <module>
    commission(0.13, 0.000725)
  File "C:/Users/WF/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/итог продажи акций2.py", line 11, in commission
    c1 = p1*b
NameError: name 'p1' is not defined
```

Comment: ошибка возникает, потому что вы переопределили переменную `price` функцией

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def price(a, b, c):
    p1 = round(b * c, 1)
    p2 = a * c
    return p1, p2


def commission(a, b, p1, p2):
    c1 = p1 * b
    c2 = p2 * b
    c3 = (p1 - p2) * 0.13
    return c1, c2, c3


def profits(p1, p2, c1, c2, c3):
    p7 = round(sum([c1, c2, c3]))   # сумма затрат
    p8 = round((p1 - p2) - p7)      # чистая прибыль

    print(f'стоимость акции при покупке - {p2}\n'
          f'стоимость акции при продаже - {p1}\n'
          f'чистая прибыль - {p8}\nналоги/комиссии - {p7}')

    return p7, p8


pricesale = float(input('Введите цену продажи:'))
p1, p2 = price(1807.3, pricesale, 6)    
c1, c2, c3 = commission(0.13, 0.000725, p1, p2)
profits(p1, p2, c1, c2, c3)
```

---

Объяснение:

1. Сначала напишите *все определения функций* (2 пустые строки после каждой из них, см. [PEP 8 - руководство по написанию кода на Python](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html)), и только *затем* все остальные команды.
2. В функции `commission()` используете переменные `p1` и `p2`. Нужно их добавить как параметры этой функции.
3. При вызове функции `price()` нужно сохранить возвращенные значения `p1` и `p2`:

   ```
   p1, p2 = price(1807.3, pricesale, 6)
   ```

   чтобы их затем применить как параметры к последующему вызову функции `commission()`.
4. Пункты 2 и 3 тоже к функции `profits()`.
5. В функции `profits()` нужно переместить команду `return` на конец, потому что она завершает вызов функции и ничего после ней не будет исполнено.
6. Вы никогда не вызываете эту функцию (`profits()`). Я добавил ее вызов.
7. Эта функция (`profits()`) возвращает значения `p7` и `p8`. Существуют 2 возможности:

   1. Они вам совсем не нужны — удалите команду `return p7, p8`.
   2. Они вам нужны для продолжения вашей программы — сохраните их, т.е. вместо вызова функции `profits()` в форме

      ```
      profits(p1, p2, c1, c2, c3)
      ```

      примените форму

      ```
      p7, p8 = profits(p1, p2, c1, c2, c3)
      ```